# Two routers on the same network

Tags: networking, home-networking

My ISP has supplied me with a modem/router all in one and it isn't very good. It loses its settings and dies frequently. So I have another router in my apartment (Linksys wrt310n) that is connected to the modem via LAN->LAN port connections.

I want to give my Linksys router the DHCP role and also have the ISP modem DMZ everything to the Linksys router. I want to be able to have all computers connected to both routers on the same network as well.

I have been able to make it so that the Linksys has a DMZ to it from the ISP modem, but ISP modem LAN port -> Linksys WAN port, so they were on different networks.

Is there a way to have it so that both of them are on the same network but the Linksys router handles DHCP and port forwarding?

Comment: What is the make/model of the crappy modem?

Comment: Gigaset SE567 Part Number: 060R-H550-A13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to http:///brgmode.htm you should be able to enable bridge mode.  What this does is stop the modem from being a router, so it is just a modem.  Connect the WAN port of the linksys to a LAN port on the modem.

Now configure pppoe on the WAN port of the 310N, and enter the same credentials as you would have on the modem.

What this is doing is turning the GE into a dumb modem that is controlled by the WRT310N.  It means that you won't be able to use any LAN ports on the GE however.  So your public IP address is owned by the WRT310N, and so you can do all the port forwarding rules on the 310N as if it were directly connected to the ADSL.

Comment: I would go with this solution but I need the ISP's router to supply some LAN ports to the area it is in. EDIT: However, I have the DHCP working on the WRT310N, but when I DMZ the ISP router to the WRT310N, the port forwarding isn't working.

Comment: Yeah, DHCP is easy, turn it off on the GE, and turn it on on the WRT.  But you are not going to get port-forwarding working through two hops *and* have the two routers LAN ports on the same network, it isn't possible.